# Cassandra DB connection Socket Exception: tried 127.0.0.1:49984

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra. I installed Cassandra in Cloud server & its up and running.
I downloaded "**No Sql Manager**" to connect to Cassandra DB. While trying to connect giving error as below.

> All hosts tried for query failed (tried 127.0.0.1:49984: SocketException 'A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied') Details: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

How to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Cassandra node running on the same node as NoSQL Manager?  If not, then you should supply the actual (external) IP address, and not 127.0.0.1.

Also, Apache Cassandra by default accepts client connections on port 9042.  I'm not sure where 49984 is coming from, but try changing that to 9042, instead.

Comment: No luck my friend. This port number is always changing automatically.  (tried 127.0.0.1:49984: SocketException) while connecting.

Comment: @vishnukarthikReddy Well, then that's likely your issue.  I've never used NoSQL Manager, but there has to be some way to force it to 9042 for it to connect to Cassandra.

Comment: Okay. will see. Could you suggest me any tool which you know/use to connect to the Remote Cassandra DBs?

Comment: @vishnukarthikReddy I know plenty of folks who use DBeaver, but otherwise the CQLSH command-line tool should work just fine.